# Dynamic Resource allocation : Allocate orders to warehouse based on cost optimization

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, combinations

I have 3 warehouse named as A, B, C which have different minimum order volume slabs . Each slab has minimum cost per order. Given total orders I havedistribute this orders into at lease one slab of each warehouse such that I always choose slab which have minimum cost.

for example :

```
Slab for warehouse  A :
A_1 = Minimum 400000 lakh order : 59.5 cps
A_2 = Minimum 500000 lakh order : 58.2 cps
A_3 = Minimum 770000 lakh order : 55.7 cps
A_4 = Minimum 1100000 lakh : 53.8 cps
A_5 = Minimum 1500000 lakh : 53.1 cps
 
 
Slab for warehouse B :
B_1 = Minimum 500000 lakh order : 63 cps
B_2 = Minimum 800000 lakh order : 59.4 cps
B_3 = Minimum 900000 lakh order : 56.5 cps
B_4 =Minimum 1200000 lakh : 53 cps
B_5 =Minimum 1500000 lakh : 52.5 cps
 
Slab for warehouse C :
C_1 =Minimum 1650000 lakh order : 54 cps
C_2 =Minimum 2000000 lakh order : 50 cps
```

If I get 300000 order then I my optimimum slab combination of different warehouse will be
There can be different combinations of case out of which giving example of 2 cases

```
Case 1:
warehouse C : minimum order 2000000 * 50 = 100000000 (if we select  C_2)
warehouse B :  minimum order 900000 * 56.5 = 50850000 (if we select  B_3)
warehouse A :  minimum order 100000 * 59.5 = 5950000 (if we select  A_1)

(100000000 + 50850000 + 5950000)/3000000 = 52.2666666667
Minimum cost for 300000 will be 52.2666666667

Case 2:
warehouse C : minimum order 2000000 * 50 = 100000000 (if we select  C_2)
warehouse B :  minimum order 130000 * 63 = 8190000 (if we select  B_1)
warehouse A :  minimum order 770000 * 55.7 = 42889000 (if we select  A_3)

(100000000 + 8190000 + 42889000 )/3000000 =50.3596666667
Minimum cost for 300000 will be 50.3596666667
```

In above two cases case 2 have minimum cost so we will choose case 2 as allocation.

Here order can be anything in numbers like 6500000 or 8000000.

I tried this but getting incorrect output

```
slabs_A = [(400000, 59.5), (500000, 58.2), (770000, 55.7), (1100000, 53.8), (1500000, 53.1)]
slabs_B = [(500000, 63), (800000, 59.4), (900000, 56.5), (1200000, 53), (1500000, 52.5)]
slabs_C = [(1650000, 54), (2000000, 50)]

total_orders = 300000

allocation = {}
remaining_orders = total_orders

def get_min_cost_slab(slabs, remaining_orders):
    min_cost = float('inf')
    selected_slab = None
    for order, cost in slabs:
        if order <= remaining_orders and cost < min_cost:
            min_cost = cost
            selected_slab = order, cost
    return selected_slab

for slabs, warehouse in zip([slabs_A, slabs_B, slabs_C], ['A', 'B', 'C']):
    selected_slab = get_min_cost_slab(slabs, remaining_orders)
    if selected_slab:
        allocation[(warehouse, selected_slab[0])] = selected_slab[1]
        remaining_orders -= selected_slab[0]

min_cost = sum(allocation.values())

print(f"Minimum cost for {total_orders} orders: {min_cost}")
print("Optimal Allocation:")
for (warehouse, slab), quantity in allocation.items():
    print(f"Warehouse {warehouse}, Slab {warehouse}_{slab}, Quantity: {quantity}")
```

Expected output as below

```
Warehouse A, Slab A_3, Quantity: 770000, cost : 770000 * 55.7 = 42889000
Warehouse B, Slab B_1, Quantity:130000, cost : 130000 * 63 = 8190000
Warehouse C, Slab C_2, Quantity:200000, 2000000 * 50 = 100000000
Total cost : (100000000 + 8190000 + 42889000 )/3000000 =50.3596666667
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize you are looking for a Python solution, but as no solutions have been posted several hours after the question was posted I will offer one in Ruby, which can be viewed as pseudo-code, which I believe could be translated to Python fairly easily.

---

We are given the following data.

```
total = 3_000_000
```

```
warehouses = {
  :A => {
    :A_1 => { :capacity =>   400_000, :cost => 59.5 },  
    :A_2 => { :capacity =>   500_000, :cost => 58.2 },
    :A_3 => { :capacity =>   770_000, :cost => 55.7 },
    :A_4 => { :capacity => 1_100_000, :cost => 53.8 },
    :A_5 => { :capacity => 1_500_000, :cost => 53.1 }
  },
  :B => {
    :B_1 => { :capacity =>   500_000, :cost => 63.0 },
    :B_2 => { :capacity =>   800_000, :cost => 59.4 },
    :B_3 => { :capacity =>   900_000, :cost => 56.5 },
    :B_4 => { :capacity => 1_200_000, :cost => 53.0 },
    :B_5 => { :capacity => 1_500_000, :cost => 52.5 }
  },
  :C => {
    :C_1 => { :capacity => 1_650_000, :cost => 54.0 },
    :C_2 => { :capacity => 2_000_000, :cost => 50.0 }
  }
}
```

---

The following Ruby methods (which I will explain) could be used.

```
def doit(warehouses, tot)
  a = warehouses.map { |k,v| v.to_a }
  a.shift
   .product(*a)
   .select { |arr| sufficient_capacity(arr, tot) }
   .min_by { |combo| cost(order_by_cost(combo), tot) }
end
```

```
def sufficient_capacity?(arr, total)
  arr.sum { |_lbl, h| h[:capacity] } >= tot
end
```

```
def order_by_cost(arr)
  arr.sort_by { |_lbl,h| h[:cost] }
end
```

```
def cost(arr, tot)
  arr.sum do |_lbl,h|
    f = [tot, h[:capacity]].min
    tot -= f
    f * h[:cost]
  end
end
```

---

We may now compute the minimum cost allocation to slabs for the data above.

```
minimum_cost_allocation(warehouses, total) 
  #=> [[:A_1, {:capacity=>400000, :cost=>59.5}],
  #    [:B_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>52.5}],
  #    [:C_2, {:capacity=>2000000, :cost=>50.0}]]
```

with minimum cost of

```
cost(minimum_cost_allocation(warehouses, total), total)
  #=> 157550000.0
```

The result can be formatted as desired from `minimum_cost_allocation`'s return value and use of the methods `order_by_cost` and `cost`.

---

See methods [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map), [Array#shift](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-shift),[Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-product), [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-select), [Enumerable#min_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by), [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), [Array#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) and [Hash#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D).

---

For the method `sufficient_capacity?` if

```
arr1 = [[:A_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>53.1}],
        [:B_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>52.5}],
        [:C_1, {:capacity=>1650000, :cost=>54.0}]]
```

then

```
sufficient_capacity?(arr1, total)
  #=> true
```

If, however,

```
arr2 = [[:A_1, {:capacity=> 400000, :cost=>59.5}],
        [:B_1, {:capacity=> 500000, :cost=>63.0}],
        [:C_1, {:capacity=>1650000, :cost=>54.0}]]
```

then

```
sufficient_capacity?(arr, total)
  #=> false
```

---

For the method `order_by_cost`,

```
order_by_cost(arr1)
  #=> [[:B_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>52.5}],
  #    [:A_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>53.1}],
  #    [:C_1, {:capacity=>1650000, :cost=>54.0}]]
```

---

For the method `cost`,

```
cost(arr1, total)
  #=> 158400000.0
```

This equals `53.1 * 1_500_000 + 52.5 * 1_500_000 + 54.0 * 0 = 158_400_000.0`

where `3_000_000 - 1_500_000 - 1_500_000 = 0`

---

The steps of the calculation are as follows.

```
a = warehouses.map { |_k,v| v.to_a }
  #=> [[[:A_1, {:capacity=>400000, :cost=>59.5}],
  #     [:A_2, {:capacity=>500000, :cost=>58.2}],
  #     [:A_3, {:capacity=>770000, :cost=>55.7}],
  #     [:A_4, {:capacity=>1100000, :cost=>53.8}],
  #     [:A_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>53.1}]],
  #    [[:B_1, {:capacity=>500000, :cost=>63.0}],
  #     [:B_2, {:capacity=>800000, :cost=>59.4}],
  #     [:B_3, {:capacity=>900000, :cost=>56.5}],
  #     [:B_4, {:capacity=>1200000, :cost=>53.0}],
  #     [:B_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>52.5}]],
  #    [[:C_1, {:capacity=>1650000, :cost=>54.0}],
  #     [:C_2, {:capacity=>2000000, :cost=>50.0}]]]
```

```
b = a.shift
  #=> [[:A_1, {:capacity=>400000, :cost=>59.5}],
  #     ...
  #    [:A_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>53.1}]]
a
  #=> [[[:B_1, {:capacity=>500000, :cost=>63.0}],
  #     ...
  #     [:B_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>52.5}]],
  #    [[:C_1, {:capacity=>1650000, :cost=>54.0}],
  #     [:C_2, {:capacity=>2000000, :cost=>50.0}]]]
```

```
c = b.product(*a)
  #=> [[[:A_1, {:capacity=>400000, :cost=>59.5}],
  #     [:B_1, {:capacity=>500000, :cost=>63.0}],
  #     [:C_1, {:capacity=>1650000, :cost=>54.0}]],
  #    [[:A_1, {:capacity=>400000, :cost=>59.5}],
  #     [:B_1, {:capacity=>500000, :cost=>63.0}],
  #     [:C_2, {:capacity=>2000000, :cost=>50.0}]],
  #      ...
  #    [[:A_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>53.1}],
  #     [:B_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>52.5}],
  #     [:C_1, {:capacity=>1650000, :cost=>54.0}]],
  #    [[:A_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>53.1}],
  #     [:B_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>52.5}],
  #     [:C_2, {:capacity=>2000000, :cost=>50.0}]]]
c.size
  #=> 50
```

`c` contains all arrays of size three where the first element is taken from `a[0]`, the second from `a[1]` and the third from `a[2]`. There are `b.product(*a).size #=> 50` elements, which equals `a[0].size*a[1].size*a[2].size #=> 5*5*2`.

```
d = c.select { |arr| sufficient_capacity(arr, tot) }
  #=> [[[:A_1, {:capacity=>400000, :cost=>59.5}],
  #     [:B_2, {:capacity=>800000, :cost=>59.4}],
  #     [:C_2, {:capacity=>2000000, :cost=>50.0}]],
  #      ...
  #    [[:A_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>53.1}],
  #     [:B_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>52.5}],
  #     [:C_2, {:capacity=>2000000, :cost=>50.0}]]]
d.size
  #=> 43
```

`d` removes from `c` (infeasible) elements whose combined capacity is less than `total`.

Lastly,

```
d.min_by { |combo| cost(order_by_cost(combo), tot) }
  #=> [[:A_1, {:capacity=>400000, :cost=>59.5}],
  #    [:B_5, {:capacity=>1500000, :cost=>52.5}],
  #    [:C_2, {:capacity=>2000000, :cost=>50.0}]]
```